# How do you force a child component to re-render on state change?

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm using React and trying to re-render a child custom input component on prop state change but it's not working.

The prop state change is being fired by a button click in the parent component for simplicity in this example, but there are other use cases where I'd like to automatically fire it when a calculation is performed.

Any suggestions on how to make this work is much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
**//Parent Component**

import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent.js'

const ParentComponent = () => {

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(123)

    const updateInputValue = () =>{
        setInputValue(6789) //<--Child component below is not updating even though the prop state has been updated
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComponent
                value={inputValue}
                setState={setInputValue}
            /> 

            <button onClick={updateInputValue}>Update</button>     
        </div>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent

====================================================================================

**//Child Component**

import React,{useState} from 'react'

const ChildComponent = (props) => {

      const[inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(props.value)//<--even though this prop state has changed, the input value does not update.  It only works the first time the component is rendered.

      return (
        <div>
          <input 
             value={inputValue} 
             onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)}
             onBlur={(e)=>props.setState(e.target.value)}
          >
          </input>
        </div>
      )
}
export default ChildComponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the `state` and `setState` from the parent to the children.

Since your child's state depends on the parent component, it would be better to pass the `setState` to it.

In doing so, you have made your child component stateless, and just a props-driven component.

Do check the sandbox link here too : https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-golick-bikb1y?file=/src/App.js:0-723

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(123);

  const updateInputValue = () => {
    setInputValue(6789); //<--Child component below is not updating even though the prop state has been updated
  };

  const onChange = (v) => {
    setInputValue(v);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent value={inputValue} onChange={onChange} />

      <button onClick={updateInputValue}>Update</button>

      <br></br>
      
      <div>{`new inputValue in Parent: ${inputValue}`}</div> //<--This is updating in parent when the state is changed.  As a sanity-check
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={props.value}
        onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
        onBlur={(e)=>props.setState(e.target.value)} //<--this is to see if the value is updated when the input loses focus.
      ></input>

      <div>{`new inputValue in Child: ${inputValue}`}</div> //<--This is to see if the value is updating in a different element in the child, which it is not.
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @PrateekThapa!  That solved this problem quickly but I'm actually trying to solve a more complicated problem where I am trying to format the text in different currencies based on a different function which looks up the currency code and that's where this is not updating.  It's a bit complicated to explain so I'll try to figure it out separately.